# What are these wires in my switch?

Tags: voltage, switches, cables

I’m working on an Arduino project for switching my light with it, but in my switch, there are two wires (if I count in/out as one.) I don’t know what the second one is.

When I measure voltage between one and two while the switch is off, the voltage is 230V as expected. When I measure the voltage between the wire 3 and 2 (while the switch is off) I get like 9V of AC. Even when I completely cut off the power from this switch, I read about 5V of AC. What is that brown wire for? (wire 1 is in and 2 is out/)

[image: Photo of the wires.]

Comment: First, mention what country you're in.  Rules, and traditional wiring practices, vary from place to place.  Second, you'll probably get a better hit rate if you try the diy stackexchange.  _Most_ of the folks here design electronic circuits, and maybe do house wiring on the side.  There's actual contracting professionals hanging out on the diy stackexchange -- maybe even one from your country.  (If it was North America, I'd suspect a ground wire -- but in a country that uses 220V?  I dunno).

Comment: I’m from Czech Republic and thanks for suggestion, I’ll try to ask there too.As I tried to find out, this doesn’t look like traditional wiring in Czechia neither, I just hoped the voltages might help you to figure out what is tha wire for.

Comment: Well, peculiar wiring done by a previous homeowner is traditional the world around, I think.  If it's normal to run ground wires, it could be that.  Someone may have run an extra wire for some reason and left it open at one end -- particularly if they needed 2-wire cable and all the store had that day was 3.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to DIY.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the brown wire is the Neutral (non-Hot) wire - not required for a switch, but would be required if you wanted to put an outlet in that box.

However, a web search suggests that Brown should be Hot 230 V and Blue should be Neutral.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the third wire needed for a three-way switch setup (where a fixture can be controlled from two different switches. There may have been a three-way switch previously wired in that box and the third wire was never removed.

The voltage may be induced voltage from running parallel to live wires.

Comment: I’m sure there could have not been three way switch previously, not to mention it doesn’t make any sense (it is just switch for one light in one room with one door and no stairs) So could it be anything else or the electrician who made this did something useless? Or does it have some use in this case?